# Dropbox and Google Drive syncing the same folder at the same time, is it posible?

Tags: dropbox, google-drive

I am interested in using Dropbox and Google Drive to sync the same folder at the same time...

Is there any special consideration to be taken into account?

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Try this http://www.joelvaldez.com/how-to-use-google-drive-and-dropbox-together/ I am not home and cannot test this but Im sure it should work.

Comment: hmm, I read the comments and it's not clear if there is a chance to mess the things up...
I'll try it, but first I have to back up all my Dropbox/GoogleDrive files to a local folder, that is not synced at all, just in case
thanks

Comment: well.... it appears that none of them, either Dropbox or GoogleDrive, allows to change the synced folder name, so you have to put one inside the other

so you end up with .../GoogleDrive/Dropbox or .../Dropbox/GoogleDrive

Comment: There are some techniques using symbolic links to arbitrarily add any directory to Dropbox/GDrive. In the case of Dropbox, though, I think they closed the most obviously loophole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what [Al Everett said in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/464431/dropbox-and-google-drive-syncing-the-same-folder-at-the-same-time-is-it-posible/465424#comment546751_464431), I backed up my files again, I started messing around with Dropbox and Gdrive, and found this:

GoogleDrive doesn't allow symlink-ing; it keeps saying "folder not empty", even when the original is indeed empty.

Dropbox, in the other hand, has no troubles using a symlink to any folder, as long as it's named Dropbox

So, both can sync to the same folder, as long as the Gdrive folder is created first and then Dropbox is configured to sync to a symlink of the "Google Drive" folder.

I guess it is a matter of time until the folks at Dropbox close that loophole too.

Finally, I added my own personal touch, by creating a symlink named "Cloud", pointing to Gdrive, and hiding both Gdrive and Dropbox on Finder.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but I'd caution you that you're getting outside of the design parameters of both apps. When it comes to my data, I don't like to mess around.

Comment: You are right, I was kind of worried about, but I am using only one linked computer, and dropbox has a kind of a remote trash basket, so I hope my precious data won't be deleted by accident. Thanks